# Как убрать черный экран после обновления Ubuntu до 23.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, обновление, fstab

Прилетела 23.04. Решил почему бы и нет... После перезапуска вылез черный экран и что-то типа этого (картинка не моя, но смысл тот же):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Гугл подсказал что надо закоментировать указанный uuid. Сообщение пропало, но черный экран остался. После этого решил попробовать поочередно закоментировать ещё пару строк. Это не помогло, fstab  в итоге перестал редактироваться и пишет file fstab is unwritable. Сейчас fstab выглядит так (первой закоментировал третью строку снизу):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А изначально был таким:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как теперь раскоментировать лишние строки и убрать черный экран?

upd: теперь при обычной загрузке выдает вот это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
А при загрузке после recovery mode все так же черный экран с курсором

upd1: мне удалось изменить fstab. Сейчас закоментировал только третья строка снизу. Черный экран с курсором вернулся)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

удалил проприетарные драйвера nvidia и система загрзилась